# Problemas ao converter um certificado .PFX para .PEM

Tags: certificado-digital, openssl, http-status-code-403

Trabalho com certificados e ocasionalmente preciso realizar a conversão de um certificado privado na extensão `.PFX` para a extensão `.PEM`, mas só consigo consumi-lo num webservice se ele for gerado sem senha, ou seja, desprotegido.

Se eu tento gerá-lo com senha (sendo igual ou não a do certificado `.PFX`), não consigo consumi-lo no webservice (recebo o erro "403 - Forbidden").

Vocês sabem me dizer por que isso ocorre?

Para gerá-lo desprotegido, utilizo o comando abaixo (através do OpenSSL):

```
pkcs12 -in certificado.pfx -out certificado.pem -nodes
```

Para gerá-lo com senha, utilizo esse:

```
pkcs12 -in certificado.pfx -out certificado.pem
```

Não consigo entender porque ocorre o erro, já que o OpenSSL não indica nenhuma falha.

Utilizo ambiente Windows, então uso uma ferramenta do OpenSSL que encontrei na internet.